# Not getting response

Tags: node.js

Getting empty array even if data is present.

Empty array in response please help me.

```
sql.query("SELECT id, latitude, longitude from businesses", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      result(err, null)
    } else {

      // result(null, data)
      let distanceArray = []
      let c = 0;
      var disDataOf = [];
      _.map(data, (d) => {
        c++;
        // console.log("c-------------", c)
        let distanceData =  getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(d.latitude, d.longitude, lat, long);
        // console.log("disatace--------", distanceData, range)
        if (distanceData < range || distanceData == range) {

          Business.getBusinessListingById(d.id, (err, finalBusinessData) => {
            if (err) {
              result(err, null)
            } else {
                disData = finalBusinessData[0]
                console.log("dis--------", disData)
                disData.distance = distanceData
                distanceArray.push(disData)
                console.log("array====================", distanceArray)
              // console.log("c-------------", c)
              // if (c == data.length-1) {
              //   result(null, distanceArray)
              // }
            }
          })
        }

      },
      result(null, distanceArray)
      )
      // result(null, distanceArray)


    }
  })
```

No error only empty array

Comment: What exactly is empty? Could you post the outputs of your `console.log`'s?

Answer (score 0):

This is the evergreen problem of your code is running `_.map` and hitting the `getBusinessListingById` async method but returning the result before actually completing the async requests.

You need to make the inner part a `Promise` and push it to array and execute it using `Promise.all`. Optimally you should use `async-await`

```
sql.query("SELECT id, latitude, longitude from businesses", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    result(err, null)
  } else {
    // result(null, data)
    let distanceArray = []
    var disDataOf = [];
    const promises = [];
    _.forEach(data, (d) => {
      // console.log("c-------------", c)
      let distanceData = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(d.latitude, d.longitude, lat, long);
      // console.log("disatace--------", distanceData, range)
      if (distanceData < range || distanceData == range) {
        promises.push(Business.getBusinessListingById(d.id));
      }
    })
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((arr) => {
        result(null, arr);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        result(err)
      })
    // result(null, distanceArray)
  }
})
```

Refer [this blog post](https://medium.com/trappedpanda/loops-asynchronous-functions-and-returning-collective-results-in-node-js-b7566285fb74) that I wrote recently just because of the frequency of this kind of questions.

Comment: I am getting null in response but data is there.

Comment: Business.getBusinessListingById(d.id, (err, mydata) => {
            if (err) {
              result(err, null)
            } else {
              console.log("data-----------", mydata[0])
              promises.push(mydata[0])
              console.log(promises)
            }
          })

Comment: using above function like this

Comment: No, please read about promises and how they work. You will not be able to figure it out without knowing the basics. You cannot use the function like that. You want to push the promise not the console log.

Comment: Why aren't you using the function exactly, or if the `getBusinessListingById` is not promise based promisify it using `utils.promisify` or manually.